# Showing this is a martingale

Tags: probability, stochastic-calculus

$$X_t = t^2 B_t - 2 \int_0^t  s B_s ds$$

where $B_t$ is standard Brownian motion.

My textbook says this is a martingale, but I'm not sure how to prove the expectation condition.

Taking conditional expectation,

$$E[X_t | \mathcal{F}_s ]  = E[t^2 B_t |\mathcal{F}_s] -2 E\left[\int_0^t  s B_s ds|\mathcal{F}_s \right] = t^2 B_s -2 \int_0^s u B_u du -2 E\left[\int_s^t u B_u  du|\mathcal{F}_s \right]$$

So presumably that last expectation should equal

$$s^s B_s - t^2 B_s$$

in order for it to be a martingale. But I don't see how to take the expectation inside, nor why it should equal $s^2 B_s - t^2 B_s$. Can someone explain how to evaluate that last expecation?

edit: Misread the question. Corrected

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess $X_t$ should be $$X_t = t^2 B_t-2 \int_0^t  s B_s ds$$ to be a martingale.
We can see that
$$
E\left[\int_s^t  r B_r dr\;|\mathcal{F}_s\right] = E\left[\int_s^t  r B_r dr\;|\mathcal{F}_s\right]=\int_s^t  r E[B_r |\mathcal{F}_s] dr = \frac{t^2-s^2}{2}B_s.
$$ Hence, we have that$$
E\left[X_t - X_s |\mathcal{F}_s\right]= t^2B_s -s^2B_s -2\cdot\frac{t^2-s^2}{2}B_s=0,
$$ showing that $\{X_t,\mathcal{F}_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ is a martingale.

Comment: @Xiaomi No Itô integral is involved in this answer.

Comment: Sorry my mistake, I mean integral involving $B_t$, even though its with respect to Lebesgue measure. Do we need justification to interchange expectation/integral?

Comment: It is a good point, we need justification to interchange integral/expectation. To this end, we need Fubini's theorem and hence need the assumption that the underlying probability measure is complete. However, if $\mathcal{F}_t$ is assumed to satisfy usual assumptions as usual, this is satisfied. If you want a rigorous justification, you can test $E[\int_s^t  r B_r dr\cdot 1_A]$ against $A\in \mathcal{F}_s$, getting $\int_s^t  r E[B_r\cdot 1_A]dr = \int_s^t  r E[B_s\cdot 1_A]dr = E[\int_s^t  r B_s dr\cdot 1_A]$.

Comment: Applying more powerful tools such as Ito's lemma is of course one way to get the same result without messy details.